# What does “an” mean at the end of a sentence

Tags: separable-verb

I’m using Rosetta Stone and have come across similar sentences like the following:

> Wen rufst du an?

What does the *an* mean and is it necessary? I’ve tried typing it into Google Translate with and without the *an* it comes up with the same meaning either way.  I also know that the German word *an* translates to *to, at, on, by*, and *against* but none of those words seem to make any sense in this sentence.

Comment: To close voters: OP obviously tried to use Google Translate as per question but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I give you two situations:

**Situation 1:**

> *English:*
>   You and Peter have been swimming in the ocean. You just came out of the water, but Peter is 30 meters away from you. You want, that Peter comes to you, so you **call** him.
>   **Who do you call?**
>
> *German:*
>   Du und Peter wart im Meer schwimmen. Ihr seid gerade aus dem Wasser gekommen, aber Peter ist 30 Meter von dir entfernt. Du möchtest, dass Peter zu dir kommt, also **rufst** du ihn.
>   **Wen rufst du?**

**Situation 2:**

> *English:*
>   You are at home alone and your computer crashed. Peter is a computer engineer and can help you, so you **call** him.
>   **Who do you call?**
>
> *German:*
>   Du bist allein daheim und dein Computer ist gerade abgestürzt. Peter ist Computerfachmann und kann dir helfen, also **rufst** du ihn **an**.
>   **Wen rufst du an?**

In situation 1 you are calling Peter without a phone. You are just speaking in a louder voice than normal. This is what *to call* meant even before the telephone was invented. In German this is »rufen«.

In Situation 2 you are using a telephone to ring up another person. You (normally) are not speaking in a louder voice, but you need a special device (a phone). This is a different meaning of *to call* than in situation 1, and it translates different into German. In German this is »anrufen«.

### Separable verb

Some German verbs have a feature that English verbs doesn't have: They can be split into two parts, whose first(!) part can float across the whole sentence to its very end:

> *German:*
>   Maria **wäscht** das Geschirr, das ihr Claudia und Walter aus dem Esszimmer gebracht haben, nachdem alle drei dort gegessen und viel geredet hatten, besonders sorgfältig und mit dem neuen Schwamm, den sie von Lisa bekommen hat, **ab**.
>
> *English:*
>   Maria **washes** the dishes, which Claudia and Walter brought her from the dining room, after all three of them had been eating and talking a lot, very carefully with the new sponge, that she has got from Lisa.

The verb in this sentence is »abwaschen« (to clean a plane surface with water), and it is a separable verb which splits into »ab« and »waschen« in some cases, and when this happens, the first part (here »ab«) moves to the end of the main sentence, while the second part (»waschen«) stays at position 2, after the subject. But as shown in my example, supporting sentences can squeeze also inside the main sentence, which makes the two parts of the verb move apart even more.

The main sentence of my example is:

> Maria wäscht das Geschirr ab.
>   Maria washes the dishes.

But see how separable verbs are used in different tenses:

- Präsens: Ich **rufe** Peter **an**. Maria **wäscht** das Geschirr **ab**.
- Perfekt: Ich habe Peter **an**ge**rufen**. Maria hat das Geschirr **ab**ge**waschen**.
- Präteritum: Ich **rief** Peter **an**. Maria **wusch** das Geschirr **ab**.
- Plusquamperfekt: Ich hatte Peter **an**ge**rufen**. Maria hatte das Geschirr **ab**ge**waschen**.
- Futur I: Ich werde Peter **anrufen**. Maria wird das Geschirr **abwaschen**.
- Futur II: Ich werde Peter **an**ge**rufen** haben. Maria wird das Geschirr **ab**ge**waschen** haben.

For both examples (*anrufen* and *abwaschen*) there exist words that are not separable: *Rufen*, as described above, and »waschen« (to wash). The latter one can be used in:

> Maria wäscht ihr Haar.
>   Maria washes her hair.

If you use those words, you get this table:

- Präsens: Ich **rufe** Peter. Maria **wäscht** ihr Haar.
- Perfekt: Ich habe Peter ge**rufen**. Maria hat ihr Haar ge**waschen**.
- Präteritum: Ich **rief** Peter. Maria **wusch** ihr Haar.
- Plusquamperfekt: Ich hatte Peter ge**rufen**. Maria hatte ihr Haar ge**waschen**.
- Futur I: Ich werde Peter **rufen**. Maria wird ihr Haar **waschen**.
- Futur II: Ich werde Peter ge**rufen** haben. Maria wird ihr Haar ge**waschen** haben.

For almost all separable verbs there is also a verb without the separable prefix, but this other verb has a different meaning.

> rufen: To call someone without a phone, by speaking louder.
>   anrufen: To ring up someone by phone.
>
> waschen: To clean something with a liquid. (water in most cases)
>   abwaschen: Te remove dirt from a plane surface with a liquid. (water in most cases) (Hair has no plane surface, so you can't use the verb »abwaschen« for it)

Comment: Great explanation, separable verbs are a brand new concept to me. Is there a way to know which verbs are separable? Also do you have to separate them? For example, would the sentence "Ich anrufe Peter" be wrong?

Comment: @batman: Here is a great resource: https://www.google.at/?gws_rd=cr&ei=bvZQVvbKBIHKsAHU9beIAg#q=separable+verbs+german And yes, »Ich anrufe Peter« is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Some verbs are split into their parts when inflected. *Anrufen* is one of them:

> Anrufen -> "Ich rufe an", but "Ich habe angerufen".

Your confusion comes from the fact that both *anrufen* and *rufen* are translated as *to call* into English, but they have different meaning:

The most common meaning of *anrufen* is *to call someone on the phone*.

The most common meaning of *rufen* is *to shout*.

Answer (score 3):

You fell victim to a very special trap that you probably were unable to spot. As other answers have pointed out, *to call* as in calling someone on the phone is translated as *anrufen.* *Anrufen* is a separable verb, so it will separate itself and create a *Verbklammer* except in cases where the *rufen* part needs to be at the end of the sentence:

> Ich will dich *anrufen.* (Future I, uses infinitive form; at the end.)
>   Ich versuche, dich *anzurufen.* (Infinitive construction; the *zu* immersed into *anrufen.)*
>   Ich habe dich *angerufen.* (Perfect tense; participle particle *ge* immersed into *anrufen.)*
>   Er will, dass ich dich *anrufe.* (Subordinate clause; requires verb at the end.)
>
> Ich *rufe* dich *an.* (Main clause present tense; generates the *Verbklammer.)*
>   Ich *rief* dich *an.* (Main clause, past tense; same as above.)

So the *an* at the end of your example sentence is part of the verb *anrufen.*

However, when you remove it to generate the sentence ‘Wen rufst du?’, you have *again* made a valid sentence because the verb *rufen* exists, too. And, to make matters worse, *rufen also* translates as *to call* but only in the sense of shouting. What a very unlucky situation to be in.

---

Summed up:

- > Wen rufst du an?

  translates to

  > Who are you calling (on the phone)?
- > Wen rufst du?

  translates to

  > Who are you calling (by shouting)?

Two verbs, different meanings but translate to the same English verb.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition »an« is part of the verb »anrufen« which means »to call« and it simply means » whom are you calling?«

Comment: It’s not a preposition in this case, it’s a particle.